# Warnings when running my web app with Glassfish 4.1.1 in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish

I have tried many things that I've found here or in other pages but it won't work for me... This is the warnings (advertencias) I get when trying to run my web app:

```
Launching GlassFish on Felix platform
may 23, 2018 7:04:28 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner createBundleProvisioner
INFORMACIÓN: Create bundle provisioner class = class com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner.
may 23, 2018 7:04:28 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner$DefaultCustomizer getLocations
ADVERTENCIA: Skipping entry  because it is not an absolute URI.
may 23, 2018 7:04:28 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner$DefaultCustomizer getLocations
ADVERTENCIA: Skipping entry  because it is not an absolute URI.
may 23, 2018 7:04:28 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner startBundles
ADVERTENCIA: Can not start bundle file:/D:/Archivos%20de%20Programa/GlassFish_Server/glassfish/modules/core.jar because it is not contained in the list of installed bundles.
Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishRuntime@a2572cb in service registry.
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : rootFolder=D:\Archivos de Programa\GlassFish_Server\glassfish
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : templateDir=D:\Archivos de Programa\GlassFish_Server\glassfish\lib\templates
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : src=D:\Archivos de Programa\GlassFish_Server\glassfish\lib\templates\logging.properties
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : dest=D:\Archivos de Programa\GlassFish_Server\glassfish\domains\domain1\config\logging.properties
Información:   Running GlassFish Version: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1.1  (build 1)
Información:   Server log file is using Formatter class: com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.ODLLogFormatter
Información:   Realm [admin-realm] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
Información:   Realm [file] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
Información:   Realm [certificate] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.certificate.CertificateRealm] successfully created.
Información:   Authorization Service has successfully initialized.
Información:   Registered org.glassfish.ha.store.adapter.cache.ShoalBackingStoreProxy for persistence-type = replicated in BackingStoreFactoryRegistry
Información:   JTS5014: Recoverable JTS instance, serverId = [100]
Advertencia:   Instance could not be initialized. Class=interface org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.AddOn, name=http-listener-1, realClassName=org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2AddOn
Información:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 20ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8080]
Advertencia:   Instance could not be initialized. Class=interface org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.AddOn, name=http-listener-2, realClassName=org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2AddOn
Información:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 33ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8181]
Advertencia:   Instance could not be initialized. Class=interface org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.AddOn, name=admin-listener, realClassName=org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2AddOn
Información:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 8ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:4848]
Información:   visiting unvisited references
Información:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 3ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:3700]
Información:   Java security manager is disabled.
Información:   Entering Security Startup Service.
Información:   Loading policy provider com.sun.enterprise.security.provider.PolicyWrapper.
Información:   Security Service(s) started successfully.
Información:   Created HTTP listener http-listener-1 on host/port 0.0.0.0:8080
Información:   Created HTTP listener http-listener-2 on host/port 0.0.0.0:8181
Información:   Created HTTP listener admin-listener on host/port 0.0.0.0:4848
Información:   Created virtual server server
Información:   Created virtual server __asadmin
Información:   Setting JAAS app name glassfish-web
Información:   Virtual server server loaded default web module 
Información:   visiting unvisited references
Información:   visiting unvisited references
Información:   Loading application [ProyectoTutorial] at [/ProyectoTuto]
Información:   Loading application ProyectoTutorial done in 1.962 ms
Información:   visiting unvisited references
Información:   visiting unvisited references
Información:   visiting unvisited references
Información:   Loading application [DLC_TPIntegrador2018] at [/DLC_TPIntegrador2018]
Información:   Loading application DLC_TPIntegrador2018 done in 174 ms
Información:   GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1.1  (1) startup time : Felix (4.756ms), startup services(3.009ms), total(7.765ms)
Información:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 1ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:7676]
Información:   JMXStartupService has started JMXConnector on JMXService URL service:jmx:rmi://192.168.0.236:8686/jndi/rmi://192.168.0.236:8686/jmxrmi
Información:   Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl@9255c05 as OSGi service registration: org.apache.felix.framework.ServiceRegistrationImpl@5bca7664.
Información:   HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.1.2.Final
Advertencia:   Instance could not be initialized. Class=interface org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.AddOn, name=http-listener-2, realClassName=org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2AddOn
Información:   Created HTTP listener http-listener-2 on host/port 0.0.0.0:8181
Información:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 5ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8181]
Advertencia:   Instance could not be initialized. Class=interface org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.AddOn, name=http-listener-1, realClassName=org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2AddOn
Información:   Created HTTP listener http-listener-1 on host/port 0.0.0.0:8080
Información:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 4ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8080]
```

If possible please give details on how to solve it, I'm not sure if I wasn't able to fix it because I did the "corrections" wrong or not.

I'm doing this project with other Uni mates and one told us to add one .dll to javajdk's bin file... And he also added the .jar of the JDBC driver in the root of the project.

Thanks in advance for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

Stop the server. Go to CMD Prompt window. Type netstat. Shows you all the ports being used. Then type “netstat -killall” to free your ports. Then run the server.